# Using Amplify for local storage when crossing protocols between HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, local-storage, amplifyjs

I am using Amplify 1.0a1 on my site and I have came across an issue with using it. I am storing the value of `prod_id` in localStorage on one page (which is under HTTP) and then I move to the 'list' page (which is under HTTPS) and I can't access the value in storage.

Looking in Firebug I can't see the value under localStorage.

```
amplify.store('list_id_to_add', prod_id);
window.location = base_url + '/list/';
```

Then on the 'list' page I have this JavaScript:

```
if(amplify.store('list_id_to_add')){        
    addStoredProductsTolist();
} else {
    console.log('theres nothing');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is not possible to share local storage values between HTTP and HTTPS.